# NameError: name '__file__' is not defined when getting the path of the current script using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console, nameerror

I am trying to run a script in the QGIS Processing Script Editor, but I get the following error:

[image]

If I run the script from the PyQGIS console it works thanks to this changes in the `console_editor.py` (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/51912/commits/a1a43e536247db394bd7b56a8a38e6b3b8c84b91).

Is there any way to use the variable `__file__` in a script run in the processing script window? I would like to get the path where my script is.

My script:

```py
import os
from os import scandir
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

def getFiles(path):
    folders = [arch.name for arch in scandir(path) if arch.is_dir()]
    subfolders = [os.path.join(path, folder) for folder in folders]
    files = []
    for item in subfolders:
        files.append([os.path.join(item + "\\", file.name) for file in scandir(item) if os.path.splitext(file.name)[1] == '.shp'])
    return files

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

files = getFiles(script_path)

def addLayer(path, name, dataProvider = None):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path, name, "ogr")
    if not vlayer.isValid():
        print("Layer failed to load!")
    else:
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
 
for list in files:
    for file in list:
        addLayer(file, file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])
```

Comment: I have the script "add_layers.py" in a folder. I open the script from the console and I run it (clicking the Run Script button, the green one)

Answer (score 4):

That may be a valid pyqgis script, but it's not a valid [processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html). You should run it from the [console script editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor), not the processing script editor.

If your script didn't raise that error (even if it was something as simple as a one line script that just defines a variable like `a = 1`), then you would still get an error because the script is not a processing script:

> #### No script found:
>
> Seems there is no valid script in the file.

[image]